# Can I apply DataLabel plug-in each graph in 'react-chartjs-2'?

Tags: charts, plugins, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

[image]

I would like to apply labels differently for bar charts, pie charts, and line charts.
(I hope to show Bar graph show dataLabel only)

Is it possible using the plugin "https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html"?

Currently, the plugin applies the same labels to all chart types.

```
Chart.defaults.set("plugins.datalabels")
```

Thanks for your suffer!

```
        <Bar
          ref={chartRef}
          data={data}
          options={options}
        />
        <Doughnut
          data={data}
        />
        <Line data={data} options={options} />
```

to

```
        <Bar
          ref={chartRef}
          data={data}
          options={options}
          plugins={ChartDataLabels}  // is is possible?
        />
        <Doughnut
          data={data}
        />
        <Line data={data} options={options} />
```

Comment: If you don't [register](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration) the plugin globally, you can do what you said, except `plugins` should be an array, so `plugins={[ChartDataLabels]}`.

Comment: However, the simplest and most natural way is to set different options for different charts. Options for the datalabels plugin are under `plugins.datalabels`; [here](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/options.html) are all the available options. To not show labels at all in a chart, set [`display: false`](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/positioning.html#visibility).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! @kikon  `plugins={[ChartDataLabels]}` that worked!!! ;D